# Spring Boot - Custom validation annotation on form not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, hibernate-annotations

I'd like to have an annotation that validates that a `MultipartFile` is an image. I've created an `@interface` and a `ConstraintValidator`, and added the annotation to my field.

Other validation annotations, like `@NotEmpty` and `@Size(min = 0, max = 2)` are working fine.

Here is the code in summary. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965098/4161471) has the same problem, but the answer doesn't work for me.

Form.java:

```
@Validated
public class Form {

    @MultipartImage
    private MultipartFile image;

    ...
}
```

@Interface MultipartImage

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

import validation.MultipartFileImageConstraintValidator;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MultipartFileImageConstraintValidator.class })
@Target({ LOCAL_VARIABLE, FIELD, METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MultipartImage {

    String message() default "{MultipartImage.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

The validator, MultipartFileConstraintValidator.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class MultipartFileConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MultipartImage, MultipartFile> {


@Override
public void initialize(final MultipartImage constraintAnnotation) {
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(final MultipartFile file, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return false;
}
```

Here's the form submit method in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/formsubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView handleForm(@Validated final Form form,
        final BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        ...
        // returns the model
    }
}
```

Validator set up in the @Configuration file, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965098/4161471

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("static")
@AutoConfigureAfter(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
public class StaticResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

...

@Bean(name = "validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}

@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    final MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    methodValidationPostProcessor.setValidator(validator());

    return methodValidationPostProcessor;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    return validator();
}

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    // Load files containing message keys.
    // Order matters. The first files override later files.
    messageSource.setBasenames(//
            // load messages and ValidationMessages from a folder relative to the jar
            "file:locale/messages", //
            "file:locale/ValidationMessages", //
            // load from within the jar
            "classpath:locale/messages", //
            "classpath:locale/ValidationMessages" //
    );
    messageSource.getBasenameSet();
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(10); // reload messages every 10 seconds
    return messageSource;
}
```

}

Comment: Oops, I hit submit too soon. I'll add more info soon.

Comment: MultipartFileConstraintValidator should implement ConstraintValidator<MultipartImage, MultipartFile>. Are other constrains like `@Size` are present in the `Form` class or you verified them in another class?

Comment: @DanielOlszewski That's a mistake, now corrected. Other constraints work in the same `Form` class

Comment: Okay, scratch that. The other constraints, like @NotEmpty, aren't working on other fields in the same Form object.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you create all these validator related beans manually and don't rely on the default configuration?

Comment: `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` is defined so that the messages can be modified. Defining `MethodValidationPostProcessor` is suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21965098/4161471) but it doesn't work whether it's in there or not.

Comment: Found [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32066557/4161471)! I'll update my question to include the code. Should my question be marked as a dupe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was information missing from my original code, specifically regarding the controller, where an additional validator is defined and bound. It uses the wrong method to include the validator `FormValidator`, and overrides the annotation validations.

`binder.setValidator(formValidator)` overrides any other validator. Instead `binder.addValidators(formValidator)` should be used!

```
@Controller
public class FormController {

     @Autowired
     final private FormValidator formValidator;

     @InitBinder("form")
     protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        // correct
        binder.addValidators(formValidator);
        // wrong
        //binder.setValidator(formValidator);
    }

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/formsubmit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleForm(@Validated final Form form, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ...
            // returns the model
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

I have also removed the Bean `MethodValidationPostProcessor` in the `@Configuration` class.